# How fix this Error: ValueError in python code with example from tensorflow (GPflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, valueerror

I am following this Notebook [here](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/GPflow/GPflow/blob/develop/doc/source/notebooks/basics/regression.ipynb) (from GPflow tutorial):

I am newbie in python, colab and tensorflow.

**Code:**

```
!pip install gpflow
# Importar Librerias
import gpflow
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import tensorflow as tf
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from tensorflow_probability import distributions as tfd
from tensorflow_probability import positive_semidefinite_kernels as tfk
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline
matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (12, 6)
plt = matplotlib.pyplot
#data = np.genfromtxt('data/regression_1D.csv', delimiter=',')
# X = data[:, 0].reshape(-1, 1)
# Y = data[:, 1].reshape(-1, 1)
# plt.plot(X, Y, 'kx', mew=2)
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
print (uploaded['datos1D.csv'][:200].decode('utf-8') + '...')
import io
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(uploaded['datos1D.csv'].decode('utf-8')))
print(df)
```

**Output:**

> IF1,CS
>   506.00,44.00
>   442.00,27.00
>   428.00,40.00
>   460.00,34.00
>   441.00,48.00
>   465.00,59.00
>   461.00,56.00
>   479.00,46.00
>   418.00,51.00
>   434.00,37.00
>   409.00,48.00
>   424.00,34.00
>   452.00,4.00
>   459.00,37.0...

```
# pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
data=df
type(data)
df.head()
df.shape
IF1= df.IF1
X=IF1[0:14]
CS = df.CS
Y=CS[0:14]
plt.plot(X, Y, 'kx', mew=2)
df.describe()
k = gpflow.kernels.Matern52(input_dim=1)
k.as_pandas_table()
m = gpflow.models.GPR(X, Y, kern=k, mean_function=None)
```

I tried to convert pandas dataset to tensorflow dataset:

```
#convert the pandas object to a tensor
X=tf.convert_to_tensor(X)
#convert the pandas object to a tensor
Y=tf.convert_to_tensor(Y)
type(X)
type(Y)
#convert the pandas object to a tensor
data=tf.convert_to_tensor(data)
type(data)
m = gpflow.models.GPR(X, Y, kern=k, mean_function=None)
```

**Another error:**

> IndexError: tuple index out of range

I can´t understad whats happen, someone help me?

Comment: First error is:
ValueError    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-79b722643f41> in <module>()
----> 1 m = gpflow.models.GPR(X, Y, kern=k, mean_function=None)
ValueError: The value must be either a tensorflow variable, an array or a scalar.

Comment: Second error (after convert to tensor dataset:ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-79b722643f41> in <module>()
----> 1 m = gpflow.models.GPR(X, Y, kern=k, mean_function=None)
IndexError: tuple index out of range